# How to get the average post-time (hour) of day in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I was trying to build a page(template) to display my "Writing behavior" of my blog. To show which hour I post most in a day of all time, I need to calculate the "average post-time (hour) of day", so that I could know like"uh I usually post blog in the morning..."

The first idea came to my mind is sum all "time(hours)" together, then divide them by "total post count", then translate to 24hour format to show up, but seems my code didn't work.

The core code I wrote is like this:

```
<?php
$alltimes=$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT sum(post_date) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post'", $alltimes));
echo '<p>Total post count '.$published_posts.'</p>';
$count_posts = wp_count_posts(); $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
$averagetime= $alltimes / $published_posts;
echo '<p>Average Time count is '.$averagetime.'</p>';
echo'<p>Average time is '.date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$averagetime).'</p>';
?>
```

My mistake is the year,month,day,hour,sec.. all summed up to "$alltimes", so when I divide it will become a disaster.

Maybe if I could get the "hour" in "post_date" but not the whole "post_date" will do the job, but how to?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The other problem with your code if you were to get it working is the figure it returns won't be the figure you're looking for. Although you're getting the average what you'll end up with is the mean when the figure you're looking for is the mode (as shown in the answer by @Cyclone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a query like this. I'm using `HOUR()` and `DATE()` to extract the date and hour parts from the datetime value:

```
SELECT HOUR(post_date) hour, COUNT(*) posts FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' && DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY posts DESC;
```

This will show how many posts have been made during different hours of the day, *notice* that this only will return rows where `post_date` match the current date. If you would like to get the most hour based on all posts you just need to remove the `DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW())` condition:

```
+------+-------+
| hour | posts |
+------+-------+
|   18 |    15 |
|   19 |    12 |
|   21 |     2 |
+------+-------+
```

If you only would like to get one single row that contains the hour with the maximum number of posts, this would work:

```
SELECT hour, MAX(posts) posts FROM ( 
  SELECT HOUR(post_date) hour, COUNT(*) posts FROM wp_posts 
  WHERE post_type ='post' && DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
  GROUP BY hour ORDER BY posts DESC 
) v;
```

or like this:

```
SELECT HOUR(post_date) hour, COUNT(*) posts FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'post' && DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY posts DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Reference**
[Mysql - Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you Cyclone, I did a little modification with your code, add it to php, but the result turns to be blank in the page: 
<pre><code>
    <?php
    $rushour = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT HOUR(post_date) hour,
    COUNT(*) posts FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'post' && DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY hour
    ORDER BY posts DESC
    LIMIT 1", $rushour);
    echo $rushour;
    ?>
</code></pre>
    Any clue about this?

Comment: Hi Cyclone, I tried your last 2 queries on phpMyadmin and it did return empty.

I deleted the " && DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW())" ,everything works well, and the result shows up as you mentioned. Anyway, thank you for your help, I look back my previous code and I was so stupid :P

Comment: @freeduke - Nice you solved it. Strange that `NOW()` isn't working for your. What is your server version?

Comment: @freeduke - I think I see the problem now. The second condition in the `WHERE` clause `DATE(post_date) = DATE(NOW())` will only return rows that where posted the under the same day as the current date (I thought that what was you wanted). If nothing was posted today then you'll get an empty result. If you would like to get rows containing the overall top hour of course you should remove this condition.

Comment: Big thanks for your help Cyclone, I'm a beginner on Wordpress and php MySQL... Have to lean these stuff myself for building my blog. Learned a lot from you, thanks!